# C Programming Change Serial Channel Mode from RS-232 to RS422

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am working on a software for testing serial channels on my setup running on Linux OS. To configure channel settings such as BAUD rate, parity, etc., I used functions in <termios.h>. However, I do not know how to change channel mode from RS-232 to RS-422 mode.

I tried to use functions in <termios.h> and some ioctl commmands.

Comment: 422 or 232 is a physical level. You need to use different hardware. There is no one universal solution. Normally different hardware is connected to different ports. I can be multiplexed  - but it is hardware design dependant.

Comment: I have a switch that allows me to change RS232 to RS422. My issue is that when i go with RS-422, my program cannot comminate with hardware.

Comment: Difficult to give an answer that fits in the bounds of StackOverflow with so little information. Is this switch a hardware switch or in code? When switching to RS-422 is the communication link connected to RS-422 supporting hardware at both ends? How are you testing that communication link? If you're using a protocol does the hardware under test support the same protocol over RS-422 as it does over RS232? Are you closing your software port before switching between link standards and opening it again before testing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is a hardware switch that allows user to swtich between RS-232, RS-422 or RS485. Also in BIOS we can select RS mode. When i test in RS-232 mode there is no problem. I found something yesterday. When i use putty terminal to send/receive a message, there is no problem. However when i use my program i am not able to send/receive a message. Putty terminal configure some flags or something else and i dont know what these are.

Comment: Are you using RS-422 or RS-485? RS-485 is half duplex with RXD and TXD sharing the same wire (actually a differential pair) and requires driver support and control from userspace. RS-422 is full duplex (a differential pair in both directions), but you may need to disable hardware flow control and modem control if the only signals are RXD and TXD.

Answer (score 0):

Interface converters which allow you to choose the physical interface do that in a vendor-specific way.

Here's an example of how it is done by MOXA uPort 11x0 USB to RS-232/422/485 adapters:

1. On the USB level, serial port settings are set by sending a USB Control message with `command` equaling `MXU1_SET_CONFIG` (0x05) and the USB packet payload consisting of a `mxu1_uart_config` struct:

```
struct mxu1_uart_config {
    __u16   wBaudRate;
    __u16   wFlags;
    __u8    bDataBits;
    __u8    bParity;
    __u8    bStopBits;
    char    cXon;
    char    cXoff;
    __u8    bUartMode;
} __attribute__((packed));
```

Notice the last field. That's what determines the physical interface which will be used. Choices are:

- `MXU1_UART_232` (0x00) - RS-232;
- `MXU1_UART_485_RECEIVER_ENABLED` (0x02) - RS-422 or RS-485-4wire;
- `MXU1_UART_485_RECEIVER_DISABLED` (0x01) - RS-485-2wire.

2. On the `ioctl` level, you choose the physical interface with the `MOXA_SET_INTERFACE` (405) ioctl. `arg` should be one of:

- `MXU1_RS232` (0);
- `MXU1_RS4852W` (1);
- `MXU1_RS422` (2);
- `MXU1_RS4854W` (3).

3. On the user (i.e. console) level, you choose the physical interface with [setserial(8)](https://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/8/setserial/):

```
# setserial /dev/ttyUSB0 port X
```

where X is one of:

- 0 - RS-232;
- 1 - RS-485 2W;
- 2 - RS-422;
- 3 - RS-485 4W.